# Function parameters convention

Tags: php, function, variable-assignment

If I have a function with dozens of parameters, is it okay to use variable names that will serve as guide?

For instance:

```
public function addUser($user,$employeeno,$streetno,$street,$city,$state,
        $zip,$mobileno,$officeno,$email,$password,$division,$something,
        $something_else,$another_thing,$one_more) {

}
```

To add a user, would it be a problem if I do something like this:

```
.... addUser($user = 'hello', $empno = '123456', $streetno = '123',
             $street = 'Stack Overflow Avenue', $city = 'Stack City',
             $state = 'SC', $zip = 99999, $mob = '1234567890' // ... and so on
```

I tried and it worked but **are there any implications I should know about?** In my more than five years of experience with PHP, I have never encountered this in sample codes and systems developed by other people. This, if it's reliable, will allow me to keep track of what information I'm passing the functions or methods.

Answer (score 2):

There is no problem, you can certainly have as many arguments as you like. Of course it will make your life easier when they are properly named.

The trouble will come when you forget the order, or even worse want to modify it - It will become hard to maintain as you will need to change everywhere where you have used the function.

You could however create a `User` class:

```
class User
{
  protected $username;

  protected $employeeNumber;

  protected $streetNumber;

  public function getUsername();

  public function setUsername($username);

  public function setEmployeeNumber($number);

}
```

Then in client code:

```
$user = new User();
$user->setUsername($user);
$user->setEmployeeNumber($employeeno);
//....
```

And then type hint on the `register()` function.

```
public function register(User $user)
{
  // Save the users data
}
```

The end result being that all the data for a user is encapsulated with the user class, so any changes will not require any further modifications to the `register` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep on using functional coding, you could always use arrays.

```
$data = array("user" => "hello", "employeeno" => 123456, "streetno" => 123, "street" => "Stack Overflow Avenue"); // etc...
addUser($data);
```

Or if you want easier to read version:

```
$data['user'] = "hello";
$data['employeeno'] = 123456;
$data['streetno'] = 123;
$data['street'] = "Stack Overflow Avenue";
addUser($data);
```

Or clean up the first version:

```
$data = array("user" => "hello", 
"employeeno" => 123456, 
"streetno" => 123, 
"street" => "Stack Overflow Avenue"); // etc...
addUser($data);
```